# Where is the definition of `warble gemjar` task?

Tags: ruby, warbler

In Warbler's code here: https://github.com/jruby/warbler/blob/master/lib/warbler/config.rb#L203

Is the next block of code:

```
  task "gemjar" do
    self.features << "gemjar"
  end
```

But surely that isn't the actual definition of `warble gemjar` because that's a one line code block doing nothing.

If that's not the definition, then does someone know where it is?

Answer (score 0):

So I found all the part that makes the actual jar file, and that's what I was looking for: https://github.com/jruby/warbler/blob/master/lib/warbler/jar.rb#L80

P.S. other parts of code which are important to the process: https://github.com/jruby/warbler/blob/master/lib/warbler/task.rb#L78, https://github.com/jruby/warbler/blob/master/lib/warbler/task.rb#L122